# Dojo form validation on button click

Tags: javascript, html, validation, dojo

I am using dojo 1.5.  I want a dojo custom validation of textfield on button click(It is not a submit button). 
I am using "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox".

If we changed button type to submit, dojo validation is working. but if we changes it to button it won't.

You can find test code here : [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/CQ93P/1/)

Please tell me how we can validate a textbutton on clicking button.

Below is my code :

```
dojo.require("dojo.parser");    
dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");    
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");


function validateForm()
{   
    // Here I want to validate text box. 

}



<table style="border: 1px solid #9f9f9f;" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="true" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"   />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="dob">Date of birth:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" onClick="return validateForm()">Validate Form</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with the fiddle you provided, but a little bit of background first:

In Dojo 1.5 and earlier, modules (dijits/widgets etc) were named and loaded a little differently than in 1.6 and later. So in Dojo <=1.5, you would see things like:

```
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" ... />
...
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.addOnLoad(function() { ... });
```

In Dojo 1.6 and later, modules were rewritten to something called the AMD format (Asynchronous Module Loader). The "dojo attributes" in HTML tags were also changed a bit to be standards compliant. So instead of the above, you would see things like:

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" ... />
...
require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Button) { ... });
```

(However, you can still use the old format in 1.6, but it is more or less considered deprecated.)

Now, in your fiddle, you have mixed the two approaches. So you use `dojo.require("some.thing")`, but also `data-dojo-type="some/thing"` attributes. This causes some problems.

However, that wasn't really your question :) You want to know how to run the validators on button click. In your code, it really is just a matter of getting the form and running its `validate()` method, like so:

```
window.validateForm = function validateForm()
{   
    var form = dijit.byId("myForm");
    if(form.validate()) {
        console.info("It was valid!");
    } else {
        console.warn("It was not valid!");
    }   
}
```

(The form also has a `isValid()` method, which checks the validity, but doesn't trigger the visual cues/warning.)

I hope that clears things up! Here's your fiddle with the fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/CQ93P/4/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you are going through this [Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/form/ValidationTextBox.html)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion buddy. But in this case we have to always select or click on textbox to validate it. I want this same functionality  on button click, like a sample case : If user forgot to enter a text into textbox then it shows blank field error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the form on a button click which is not a Submit button, then refer to the following code snippet.

```
window.validateForm = function validateMyForm()
{
   var myForm = dijit.byId("myForm");
   if(myForm.validate())
     console.log("The form validation success..");
   else
     console.log("The form validation failed..");
}
```